# Is it possible to have other UIControls on a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UITableView with 3 sections inside of a UIViewController. Is it possible to have other controls above the UITableView for example a UISlider or a UIImage? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Note: These controls should not be in a UITableViewCell, they should be part of the view.

Comment: Have you tried straight-up [myTableView addSubview:x]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add a UIView to the table header or footer, see the [tableHeaderView and tableFooterView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView) properties.  A UIView could be a UIControl or a view that contains UIControls.